# Change EditText password mask character to asterisk (*)

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there any way to change the password text from dot(.) to asterisk(*) .

Password is entering  in edittext.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/passWord1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:password="true"/>
```

Comment: Note to replies: the EditText shown *is already* `password=true`. The question is about how to display a `*` instead of a `·` character.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11597660/1777090 . Hope it helps

Comment: Example app doing just that: https://github.com/luskan/TextBoxWithPassword

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Insert edittext in your xml file,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passWordEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
```

and your class file go on and get findViewById from edittext and implement for this,

```
EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passWordEditText);
edittext.setTransformationMethod(new AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

and This class implement for that,

```
public class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }
 
    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
};
```

**And If your code is Kotlin you can use this instead,**

```
class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod : PasswordTransformationMethod() {
    override fun getTransformation(source: CharSequence, view: View): CharSequence {
        return PasswordCharSequence(source)
    }

    private inner class PasswordCharSequence(private val source: CharSequence) : CharSequence {
        override fun get(index: Int): Char {
            return '*' // This is the important part
        }

        override val length: Int
            get() = source.length // Return default

        override fun subSequence(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int): CharSequence {
            return source.subSequence(startIndex, endIndex) // Return default
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I my case, I have to hide last 10 numbers, NOT all. So, I just have to override the method charAt(int index) to return '*' if index > 9 else return mSource.charAt(index).

Comment: Nice work mate! Do you know what is the default char? In my case I have to show the first 3 char and than just the default password masking char, NOT the '*'.

Comment: This removes the lapse where the actual text is displayed first before the 'password' character. Any idea how it will be retained?

Comment: Has anyone tried putting a log in charAt() method, I see that its been called thousands of times.

Answer (score 19):

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/passWord1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPassword"//here is the change. check it once in your xml
        android:password="true"/>
```

In eclipse there will be hints when you click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> when you move cursor at `android:inputType`. Then you can see list of options. there you can select `textPassword`

If you want to see `*` in place of `.` then check this [`Android: Asterisk Password Field`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051962/change-edittext-password-mask-character-to-asterisk)

Comment: I think  android:password="true" do the same. The password should be number . So I give  android:inputType="number"

Answer (score 10):

Got answer with help of link posted by Ram kiran

```
text.setTransformationMethod(new AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod());


public class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
@Override
public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
    return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
}

private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
    private CharSequence mSource;
    public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
        mSource = source; // Store char sequence
    }
    public char charAt(int index) {
        return '*'; // This is the important part
    }
    public int length() {
        return mSource.length(); // Return default
    }
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
        return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
    }
}
};
```

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i needed! what if i want to make it display the character and then asterisk-ize it after user types in another character, would i use this method alongside a textwatcher interface?

Comment: But its not working with app:passwordToggleDrawable

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin

```
class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod : PasswordTransformationMethod() {

    override fun getTransformation(source: CharSequence, view: View): CharSequence {
        return PasswordCharSequence(source)
    }

    inner class PasswordCharSequence (private val source: CharSequence) : CharSequence {

        override val length: Int
            get() = source.length

        override fun get(index: Int): Char = '*'

        override fun subSequence(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int): CharSequence {
            return source.subSequence(startIndex, endIndex)
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**In Kotlin way:**

class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod: PasswordTransformationMethod() {

```
override fun getTransformation(source: CharSequence?, view: View?): CharSequence {
    return super.getTransformation(source, view)
}


 abstract inner class PasswordCharSequence(val source: CharSequence) : CharSequence {
     override val length: Int
         get() = source.length

     override fun get(index: Int): Char =
         '*'

    override fun subSequence(start: Int, end: Int): CharSequence {
        return source.subSequence(start, end) // Return default
    }
}
```

}`

Answer (score 2):

```
EditText.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

For android:inputType, there is a type of password.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Comment: I recommend this answer. `password` property is deprecated.