# Android password edit text showing text

Tags: android, passwords, android-edittext

I have used one `Edittext` with attribute `android:inputType="textPassword"`.

But when I type some text in it, text is getting visible character by character before changing to solid bullets.

How can I make the text invisible as the user inputs the text.

Please help me.

Comment: Try to    `android:inputType="text"` or  `edt_password
    .setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());`

Comment: can you show your EditText from your layout..

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `EditText` attribute

`android:inputType="text"`

And also add programmatically

`edt_password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());`

Comment: I have done as you said. Still the problem is not resolved. When I type some text(say one letter), after sometime it is turning into solid bullet.

Comment: @user3021918 this thing is perfect working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

i have used the below in my application and text does not appear. Worked for me!

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/OldpwdET"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/change_password_oldpwdET"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
        android:inputType="textPassword">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

in edittext layout

```
  android:inputType="text"
```

and in your code.,put this.

```
  mEditText.setTransformationMethod(new AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

Comment: but I didn't find any class with name `AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod` in Android SDK...

Comment: it is the name of any class.which we are using.,see herehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051962/change-edittext-password-mask-character-to-asterisk

Comment: Anyway! `AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod` class is your custom class... it's not in API. You need to post that class also or provide a link...