# How to hide password first hint

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

When we enter `password` in the edittext `inputType="textPassword"`. the character anyone enters is seen for some seconds before it converts to bullets. how to `disable` that ?

Comment: You need show code and library details, we cant guess what you have written?

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma the library i am using is https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

Comment: If you mean "always show pure bullets", probably you need to create your own subclass of `PasswordTransformMethod`. However, please only do this if you are also offering a checkbox or something to disable the masking entirely. While "shoulder surfing" can be an issue, it is not *always* an issue (e.g., privacy of one's own home). Text entry in mobile devices is painful enough as is; not being able to see when you make a typo makes it that much harder.

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma it is a standard android behavior. u can try entering a password in any app. every new character is visible before it converts to bullets

Comment: @CommonsWare yes i meant that. thanks. i will what i can do

Comment: gotcha....this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900095/android-password-edit-text-showing-text

Answer (score 0):

From [Android password edit text showing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900095/android-password-edit-text-showing-text)

```
edt_password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```