# Edittext Fonts Are Not Displaying

Tags: android, android-edittext, custom-controls, android-typeface

I'm going through a weird problem.

I have created **CustomEdittext class** for setting `Typeface` for whole application and it works successfully in nearly all cases.

I am using `circo.ttf`

The problem is that when I set **`android:inputType="textPassword"`**, text stops displaying after typing, maybe because the font doesn't have a password symbol or maybe there is some other problem.

Below is an example of my issue :

[image]

**CustomEdittext.java**

```
public class CustomEdittext extends EditText {

    public CustomEdittext(Context context) {
        super(context);
        changeFonts(context);

    }
    public CustomEdittext(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        changeFonts(context);
    }

    public CustomEdittext(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        changeFonts(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void changeFonts(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Typeface tface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/circo.ttf");
        this.setTypeface(tface);
        this.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#921c50"));
        Log.i("Input Type", "Type : "+this.getInputType());
    }
}
```

**login_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <com.equest.cwely.customviews.CustomTextview
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="@color/border_pink"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <com.equest.cwely.customviews.CustomEdittext
        android:id="@+id/edt_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </com.equest.cwely.customviews.CustomEdittext>

    // this is password field
    <com.equest.cwely.customviews.CustomEdittext
        android:id="@+id/edt_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/border_pink"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="Login" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/border_pink"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="Sign Up" />    
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn_login,btn_signup;
    EditText edt_username,edt_password;
    String result = "";
    String username = "",password = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_main);

        edt_username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
        edt_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
        edt_password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
        btn_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                username = edt_username.getText().toString();
                password = edt_password.getText().toString();
                //new doLogin().execute();
            }
        });

        btn_signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: yup... help me to solve this problem

Comment: just curious, what would happen if instead of inputType, you use deprecated android:password=true?

Comment: instead of setting color in your method try setting it in the xml file.

Comment: I have tested your code and i think this problem happens due to font so try use another font and let me know.

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic : using `android:password=true` doesn't make any difference.. problem is still there..

Comment: @KaranMer : setting color doesn't cause problem. I've already tried that..

Comment: must be font then, last thing I remember reading somewhere that someone used otf instead of ttf, but not quite sure. as haresh suggested try with other font

Comment: i have to use this fonts in my application.. so can I use any method to put symbols there ??

Comment: @Prag's,i think there is another solution is try use default EditText for password EditText and just set color as you wish,so this way you can't stop app to use custom font and i think this things happens in special character like password input type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the font that you have included does not contain a character for the symbol used by default for password transformation.  You have two options:

1. Use a different font
2. Change the mask character to something that the font does contain.

Because I speculate you're not a quitter, here's some code that will change the mask character from a dot ( **•** ) to an asterisk ( * ).

First you must make your own [`PasswordTransformationMethod`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.html) to override the default:

```java
public class AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            // This is where we make it an asterisk.  If you wish to use 
            // something else then change what this returns
            return '*'; 
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
};
```

Finally you set your new transformation method to the `EditText` you wish to mask.

```
edt_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
edt_password.setTransformationMethod(new AsteriskPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

I used information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051962/change-edittext-password-mask-character-to-asterisk).