# Custom EditText Password Dots

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I need `EditText` with password `inputType` that looks like this:

[image: this]

How can i do something like it? I mean, I need to display custom drawable instead of a character. I know how to display an asterisk (*), but what about a drawable for each char?

Comment: do you use custom fonts?

Comment: Try this... Custom dots....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797824/how-to-use-custom-image-for-edittext-password-like-axis-bank-app

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387026/edittext-fonts-are-not-displaying

Comment: @Er. Arjun saini, they use 6 different edittexts. I need one, + the star is displayind by `setBackgroundResource`, but i already use it to make my edittext looks like it do. So if i change backround nothing good will happens.

Comment: @Prag'sシ, they use custom font + dots change to asterisk

Comment: ok create PasswordTransformationMethod  and add it to editText. In PasswordTransformationMethod  you can replace dot with astrick. as given in above link.

Comment: @Prag'sシ, i can replace only with `char` ? If you saw the picture in my question, i need to replace dot with drawable.

Comment: ok but how can you add multiple drawables in EditText ?? Thats bad idea.