# Customize Edittext input character to image?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to customize an edittext when user input a character and then edittext changes it to image.
Look like the image : [image]

**Note** : ● is an image not a symbol.

Comment: You could replace the char with a * when user inputs something. save the text the user entered using EditorActionListener before replacing with *.. not sure about the image though

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Now i'm not yet do anything. cause i have no experience with it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you need to extend `PasswordTransformationMethod` and use `setTransformationMethod` method of `EditText`.

```
edt.setTransformationMethod(new CustomPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

and paste this `CustomPasswordTransformationMethod`

```
class CustomPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence source;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            this.source = source;
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            if(index>4) //your own condition, when you want to hide characters.
                return 0x2022; // change this to bullets you want like '*' or '.'
            return source.charAt(index);
        }
        public int length() {
            return source.length();
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return source.subSequence(start, end);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code will write character as it is upto 5 character, after that it will print bullets in `EditText`.

Reference taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051962/change-edittext-password-mask-character-to-asterisk) post

***UPDATE***

Finally here is your answer :

```
Spannable.Factory spannableFactory;
int lastIndex = -1;

spannableFactory = Spannable.Factory
            .getInstance();
```

1. add `addTextChangedListener` in your `EditText`.

```
    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);

    TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           if (start>4) {
               mEditText.removeTextChangedListener(watcher);
               mEditText.setText(getIconText(context, s, start));
               mEditText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
               mEditText.setSelection(s.length());
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

       }
    };
```

2. Convert your drawable into `Spannable`

   ```
   public Spannable getIconText(Context context, CharSequence text, int index) {
      Spannable spannable = spannableFactory.newSpannable(text);
      if (index>lastIndex) {
          spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, R.drawable.bullet_point),
                index, index + 1,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      }
      lastIndex=index;
      return spannable;
   }
   ```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks. but i don't  want change it to bullets or '*', i want change to image.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say if you want to replace the character **b** with character **●**. Then you can add **TextWatcher** for this, which looks like this

```
 myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            StringBuilder myText = new StringBuilder(myEditText.getText().toString());
            if (myText.toString().contains("b")){ //If this contains b
                myText.setCharAt(myText.indexOf("b"),'●');
                myEditText.setText(myText.toString()); //Sets the string to EditText
                myEditText.setSelection(myText.length()); //Moves cursor to the last after replacing
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

we can use [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) for Placing the image but cant place it as a character at exact position. we can define the bounds only.

Comment: he has to change it with image not with any character, do you have any idea to do that ??

Comment: @AnujSharma we can use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` for that but cant place it as a character at exact position. we can define the bounds only.

Answer (score 2):

use property of edittext inputtype in your xml

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Comment: android:inputType="textPassword"  change all character to mask
but i want some character are not mask and other are the mask with my image mask.

Comment: @HuoChhunleng in that case you need to customise PasswordTransformationMethod make custom class which extends PasswordTransformationMethod and implement your logic

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your code. [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

```
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTest);
    text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null,
                       getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawable), null);
```