# Change visible EditText in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, user-interface, android-edittext

I want to change edittext from picture 1 to picture 2. This is my code for picture 1

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_key"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18"
            android:textFontWeight="500"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_password"
            />
```

Picture 1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7qbM.png)
Picture 2:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPoVc.png)

Can change picture 1 to picture 2

Comment: This might be helpful for you -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/14052431/7312234