# How to use custom image for edittext password like axis bank app

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to use custom image instead of '*' in edittext password field?

see image:

[image: custom paasword edittext]

Any answer or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you went trough [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.html#getTransformation%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.view.View%29)

Comment: hey thanks guys will check your links

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani, well, the only way I know of that makes it possible to do this is by customizing the EditText, something seen here:[Custom EditText](http://alinberce.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/android-edittext-with-custom-font-and-clear-button/)

Comment: @André.C.S thanks for the reply but that is not working in my case as i want to show image whereas that link shows about customizing text inside edittext. BTW thanks buddy for the suggestion

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani, That's right, it's about customizing text :), was just a way of saying that you certainly will have to do something, to show a hint as drawable!

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani, have you found my answer helpful or useful somehow?

Comment: @mmBs thanks buddy yes your answer was very useful for me. and i am going to award you the bounty...thank a lot dear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer comes from [this tutorial](http://nikshits.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/edittext-with-star-image-for-password/) and it covers a behaviour when a user:

- enters into the login screen, keyboard will open automatically.
- tries to enter value in it then textbox background changes to textbox with star background.
- tries to cancel/delete the input value by using back key on keyboard then textbox background will change to textbox without star background.

First of all you have to create two `drawables`:

[image]

[image]

Then, according to this approach, you have to implement `addTextChangedListener` method on your `EditText`. After that, as a parameter, you create a new instance of a `TextWatcher` class and you implement its methods:

```
etxtPin1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          if(etxtPin1.getText().toString().trim().length()==1){

          etxtPin1.clearFocus();
          etxtPin2.requestFocus();
          etxtPin1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pin_txt_bg_star);

          }
       }
    });
```

Then, you have to implement `setOnKeyListener` and its method `onKey`:

```
this.etxtPin1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
      public boolean onKey(View paramView, int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent) {
           if ((paramKeyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(paramInt == 67) && (LoginActivity.this.etxtPin2.getText().length() == 0)) {
               etxtPin1.requestFocus();
               etxtPin1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pin_txt_bg);
               etxtPin1.setText("");
           }

           return false;
       }
    });
```

[image]

---

**Another approach:** create you own class which extends [PasswordTransformationMethod](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.java).

```
public class MyPasswordTransformationMethod extends PasswordTransformationMethod {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
        return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
    }

    private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
        private CharSequence mSource;
        public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
            mSource = source; // Store char sequence
        }
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return '*'; // This is the important part
        }
        public int length() {
            return mSource.length(); // Return default
        }
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
        }
    }
};
```

Reference: [In android how to show asterisk (*) in place of dots in EditText having inputtype as textPassword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597648/in-android-how-to-show-asterisk-in-place-of-dots-in-edittext-having-inputtyp/11597660#11597660)

Answer (score -2):

I think simple way is, you have to define 6-edittext in xml layout.
and set width and height with custom background resorces.

Like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#9999" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="1dp"
    android:topRightRadius="1dp" />
```

and read all edittext value.
I am not sure but it will help you.