# Splitted EditText for every character in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to create custom `EditText` so it will look like this:

[image]

I need it to be single `EditText`. Is it possible to do it, or do I need to create `EditText` for every character?

Comment: Yes it is possible, have you tried? What are you struggling with?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. I'm new in Android world and couldn't find any information about it. If you could point the correct direction, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I have no idea what that image is supposed to represent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible! create multiple edit text's depending on the number of characters you want to accept as input and make sure to limit the size of each edit text to 1

```
android:maxLength="1"
```

You can set the width of each edit text and place them horizontally one after the other

Comment: That's not the solution I was looking for. I need it to be one `EditText`, but characters visually separated as shown above. Still, thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

> You can create custom `EditText` by extending it. And you have to implement **addTextChangeListener** and their you can draw whatever you want. But No need to **re Invent** the wheel

And you can also use some build in `customView` like

- [PinView](https://github.com/DavidPizarro/PinView)
- [Another](https://github.com/Philio/PinEntryView)

Also have a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849287/3496570)