# Edittext password is always showing the password

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText to enter the password and i set inputType as "textPassword". But when i run it in app or emulator the password is visible. Why it is showing password instead of dots?

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/etPassword"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:inputType="textPassword"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="@string/Password"
 android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
 android:maxLength="15"
 android:background="@drawable/ss"/>
```

drawable file ss:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
<padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
<solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#CCCCCC" />
```

### Complete Layout:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/foodstall"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#ffffffff">

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/Username"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:background="@drawable/ss"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                                     android:hint="@string/Password"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:background="@drawable/ss"
                android:text="askdjhkashdjasdksakdkaskdhkashkdhkashdkjhakshdkjhaskhdkj"/>

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:background="@color/button"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:background="@drawable/ss"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRegisterLink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/Newuser"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fpass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_forgotpass"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you try removing `maxLength` and see if still same problem

Comment: @hrskrs - Not worked.

Comment: Can you show your UI with some value in edittext?

Comment: @user2269164 try removing the background. Also, you could try to only put in <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        /> just to test it, this should definitely work. If this doesn't work, something is really wrong.

Comment: I just tried and it works fine. What API are you running?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597648/in-android-how-to-show-asterisk-in-place-of-dots-in-edittext-having-inputtyp/11597660#11597660

Check this

Comment: @hrskrs - API 24

Comment: are you using TextInputLayout above EditText?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code. Try by adding static text in the XML or check whether you are referencing the correct edittext.

Comment: Is there some change in your styles.xml

Comment: @AshwinMothilal - Field is showing dots when there is a static text.

Comment: @KeyurThumar - I saw the code but that is to display asterik instead of other character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Remove android:inputType="textPassword" from your xml file and instead, in set it in java:

```
  EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_text);
  password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

With this approach, the hint font looks good but as you're typing in that edit field, you don't see each character in plain text before it turns into a password dot. Also when making input in fullscreen, the dots will not appear, but the passoword in clear text.

2) Leave android:inputType="textPassword" in your xml. In Java,passwordMethod:

```
  EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password_text);
  password.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

This approach gave password dots.

Comment: @user2269164 try this two case.

Comment: @user2269164 Please do accept answer that it can useful for other.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding android:password="true" in EditText. It should work.

```
    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/etPassword"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:inputType="textPassword"
      android:password="true"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="@string/Password"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:maxLength="15"
      android:background="@drawable/ss"/>
```

Comment: This should work, but it's deprecated. You really shouldn't use that unless there is absolutely no other way.

Comment: @Amey - I tried but it is not working also it is deprecated in API 24.

Comment: @Amey Attribute android:password is deprecated from api 23.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue what work for me is:

I added this xml property to my EditText and it works fine:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

I know its deprecated, but `android:maxLines="1"` not working although its the replacement for singleLine.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this is working fine

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textWebPassword"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:maxLength="15" />
```

change your inputType from

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

to

```
android:inputType="textWebPassword"
```

Comment: Still password is visible.